# Is Trading 212 fair and legitimate broker for buying ETFs?

Tags: investing, etf, starting-out-investing, commission

I am looking for a way to make an investment into an ETF. Many of the low cost international brokers are unavailable in my country while the local banks have fairly high commissions. I got a suggestion to use Trading 212.

It seems very suspicious that they apparently have [no commissions at all](https://www.trading212.com/en/Trading-Conditions?tab=INVEST). And they also seem to [give out](https://www.trading212.com/en/Frequently-asked-questions?cId=9) free shares on sign up.

Is this site legitimate? If so, how do they make money? Are the commissions somehow hidden?

Comment: It costs 0.5% per currency conversion, is one way they'll make some  money.  Check out the [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avuscapital.trading212&hl=en) site.  It says they've had over 5 million downloads.  I reckon they're not illegitimate with that number of downloads.

Comment: @PeterK. It says 0% currency conversion charge on the investment tab, the 0.5% seem to only apply for CFD trading.

Comment: Zero commission has recently become the standard, so nothing suspicious about it.